# Correct format for list resource by subscription Azure logic app connector's filter field

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm working on a Azure logic app to list all the container instances within the Azure AD.
Basic process is like this,

1. List all the subscriptions
2. Foreach subscription list all resources

However I am having difficulty to filter out the resource by type. What is the correct format to use in the filter field?
I already tried using `equals(type, 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups')` but it gives the following error,

```
Invalid $filter 'False' specified in the query string.
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use an OData filter expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct format for list resource by subscription Azure logic app connector's filter field

You don't need any filter to get container groups in Azure Ad, you can simply use the below design, connectors and actions to get the required result:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Get_a_list_of_container_groups_in_a_subscription_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['aci']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['subscriptionId'])}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
                            "queries": {
                                "x-ms-api-version": "2019-12-01"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('List_subscriptions')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "List_subscriptions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "List_subscriptions": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['arm']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/subscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2016-06-01"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "aci": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/aci",
                    "connectionName": "aci",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/aci"
                },
                "arm": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/arm",
                    "connectionName": "arm",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/arm"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja , this unblocked the issue I was having 

Comment: @Shehan Weerasooriya, Glad your issue got resolved?!!!

Answer (score -1):

It helps to understand that most (if not all?) tasks use the azure api that you can look at to understand it a little better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list#code-try-0

The API example is like `resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Insights/components'` so dont try to use a function in the UI, just paste in to the filter box the string verbatim like "resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Insights/components'".